# CUDA , finding Max using reduction, error

Tags: cuda, max, reduction

here is my code trying to do reduction to find maximum of a 50 value array in a block. I have padded the array to 64.

For threads 1-31 I have correct maxVal printing out but for threads 32-49 it's a completely random number. I dont know what I am doing wrong.

btw. I thought I dont need to _sync every line in unrolling but apparently I have to. any suggestion about that?

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
//block size = 50


__syncthreads();

if (tid<32){

    cptmp[tid]=(cptmp[tid]< cptmp[tid+32]) ? cptmp[tid+32] : cptmp[tid];__syncthreads();    
    cptmp[tid]=(cptmp[tid]< cptmp[tid+16]) ? cptmp[tid+16] : cptmp[tid];__syncthreads();
    cptmp[tid]=(cptmp[tid]< cptmp[tid+8]) ? cptmp[tid+8] : cptmp[tid];  __syncthreads();    
    cptmp[tid]=(cptmp[tid]< cptmp[tid+4]) ? cptmp[tid+4] : cptmp[tid];  __syncthreads();
    cptmp[tid]=(cptmp[tid]< cptmp[tid+2]) ? cptmp[tid+2] : cptmp[tid];  __syncthreads();    
    cptmp[tid]=(cptmp[tid]< cptmp[tid+1]) ? cptmp[tid+1] : cptmp[tid];  __syncthreads();

}

__syncthreads();

//if (tid==0) {
    maxVal=cptmp[0];
    if(bix==0 && biy==0) cuPrintf(" max:%f x:%d y:%d\n", maxVal, blockIdx.x, blockIdx.y);
//}
```

Comment: Difficult to figure out what's happening without describing your thread/block/grid structure and also how you're calculating `tid`.

Comment: My block dimension is 50 so tid=threadIdx.x is between 0-49. grid size is (40, a big number). each block is finding the max in the cptmp array which is shared with size of 64. maxVal is also shared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a more efficient (at least on Fermi GPUs) and correct code using volatile.  Replace T with your type (or use a template):

```
if (tid<32) {
    volatile T *c = cptmp;
    T t = c[tid];
    c[tid] = t = (t < c[tid+32]) ? c[tid+32] : t;
    c[tid] = t = (t < c[tid+16]) ? c[tid+16] : t;
    c[tid] = t = (t < c[tid+ 8]) ? c[tid+ 8] : t;
    c[tid] = t = (t < c[tid+ 4]) ? c[tid+ 4] : t;
    c[tid] = t = (t < c[tid+ 2]) ? c[tid+ 2] : t;
    c[tid] = t = (t < c[tid+ 1]) ? c[tid+ 1] : t;
}
```

Why is this more efficient?  Well, for correctness in the absence of `__syncthreads()` we must use a volatile pointer to shared memory.  But that forces the compiler to "honor" all reads from and writes to shared memory -- it can't optimize and keep anything in registers.  So by explicitly always keeping `c[tid]` in the temporary `t`, we save one shared memory load per line of code.  And since Fermi is a load/store architecture which can only use registers as instruction operands, that means we save an instruction per line, or 6 instructions total (about 25% overall, I expect).

On the old T10/GT200 architecture and earlier, your code (with volatile and no __syncthreads()) would be equally efficient because that architecture could source one operand per instruction directly from shared memory.

This code should be equivalent if you prefer `if` over `?:`:

```
if (tid<32) {
    volatile T *c = cptmp;
    T t = c[tid];
    if (t < c[tid+32]) c[tid] = t = c[tid+32];
    if (t < c[tid+16]) c[tid] = t = c[tid+16];
    if (t < c[tid+ 8]) c[tid] = t = c[tid+ 8];
    if (t < c[tid+ 4]) c[tid] = t = c[tid+ 4];
    if (t < c[tid+ 2]) c[tid] = t = c[tid+ 2];
    if (t < c[tid+ 1]) c[tid] = t = c[tid+ 1];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much harrism. Although still I'm not very comfortable with the concept of volatile. Is is possible to use similar method for summation too ? would you please tell me how if possible ?

Comment: Please see the "reduction" sample in the NVIDIA CUDA SDK.  The basic idea for summation is `c[tid] = t = c[tid+32] + t;`

Comment: Thanks harrism. This works pretty well. for record I put the piece here:  if (tid<32){
  volatile float *c = tmp;
  float t = c[tid]; 
  c[tid] = t = c[tid+32] + t;
  c[tid] = t = c[tid+16] + t;
  c[tid] = t = c[tid+8] + t;
  c[tid] = t = c[tid+4] + t;
  c[tid] = t = c[tid+2] + t;
  c[tid] = t = c[tid+1] + t;
 }

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `__syncthreads()` in a divergent code!
Either all threads or no threads from a given block should reach every `__syncthreads()` at the same location.

All threads from a single warp (32 threads) are implicitly synchronised, so you don't need `__syncthreads()` to put them all together. However, if you are worried that shared-memory writes of one thread may not be visible by another thread of the same warp, use `__threadfence_block()`.

To elaborate the importance of `__threadfence_block()`. Consider the following two lines:

```
cptmp[tid]=(cptmp[tid]< cptmp[tid+2]) ? cptmp[tid+2] : cptmp[tid];
cptmp[tid]=(cptmp[tid]< cptmp[tid+1]) ? cptmp[tid+1] : cptmp[tid];
```

It may compile into something like this:

```
int tmp; //assuming that cptmp is an array of int-s
tmp=cptmp[tid];
tmp=(tmp<cptmp[tid+2])?cptmp[tid+2]:tmp;
tmp=(tmp<cptmp[tid+1])?cptmp[tid+1]:tmp;
cptmp[tid]=tmp;
```

While it would be correct for a single-threaded code, it obviously fails for CUDA.

To prevent optimisations like that you either declare your `cptmp` array as `volatile`, or add this `__threadfence_block()` between the lines. That function ensures that all threads of the same block see the shared-memory writed of the current thread, before the function exist.

A similar `__threadfence()` function exists to ensure global-memory visibility.

Comment: Thanks so much for these information CygnusX1. I used both the __threadfence_block() method and volatile trick and apparently they both work just perfectly. but do you know which one has better performance?

Comment: The performance difference is probably negligable. I would say that `__threadfence_block()` gives you more freedom: you say precisely where the shared memory writes have to be visible. Statig `volatile` for your variable forces the shared memory writes everywhere, even when somewhere using a temporary register may be OK and beneficial.

Comment: Fences are actual instructions, so they are more expensive than volatile -- assuming your code does not force excessive reads from shared memory.  See my answer for a more efficient code (would put it in a comment if I could fit it and format it).

Answer (score 1):

For everybody who will stumble upon this thread in the future, as I did, here is an advice in addition to harrism answer - it might be worth from performance point of view to consider shuffle operation, so the updated code to get max out of 64 elements using single warp would look like this:

```
auto localMax = max(c[tid], c[tid + 32]);    
for (auto i = 16; i >= 1; i /= 2)
{
    localMax = max(localMax, __shfl_xor(localMax, i));
}
c[tid] = localMax;
```

Only two reads and one write from global memory needed, so it is pretty neat.